# Image slightly shifting left/right on browser resize

Tags: html, css, image

I'm having an issue where my top header images shift back and forth (left & right) ever so slightly when resizing the browser.  It's hardly noticeable, but it really bugs me.  Unfortunately I don't have anything up yet for public viewing, but below is the pertinent CSS and HTML code.

```
img.displayed {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#menu{
position: static;
width:979px;  /*---Give UL a width ---*/
list-style:none;  /*--- Makes the bullets go away ---*/
margin:0;  /*--- Take out any default margin on the UL tag ---*/
padding:0;  /*--- Take out any default padding on the UL tag ---*/
margin:0 auto;  /*--- Center the menu ---*/
}

#menu li{
float:left;  /*--- Make the list go horizontal ---*/
margin:0;
}

#menu li a{
display:block;  /*--- Make the entire button area clickable rather than the text alone ---*/
text-indent: -9999px; /*--- Push the text off screen to hide text---*/
overflow: hidden; /*--- Makes text outside of bounding box hidden ---*/
height:48px;    
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
<body>
  <img class="displayed" src="./images/header.jpg" width="979" height="260" alt="" title="" />

<!-- Header Menu -->
    <ul id="menu">
        <li id="left">
            <a class="current" href="#">Left</a>
        </li>
        <li id="home">
            <a class="current" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li id="scents">
            <a href="#">Scents</a>
        </li>
        <li id="about">
            <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li id="shows">
            <a href="#">Shows</a>
        </li>
        <li id="stores">
            <a href="#">Stores</a>
        </li>
        <li id="contact">
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <br class="clear">
    </ul>

    <!--main page content removed-->
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a capture of what it looks like when the image is shifted:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ffdU.png

Here is a capture of what it looks like when it is correct:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2elS.png

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Site Note: the <head> Tag does not meant, to put your website header inside. It contains information like page title, charset, expiration date etc. Please move your image down into <body>, e.g. between <body> and <ul>

Comment: Thanks.  That was actually a copy/paste snafu.

Comment: Are you using any type of CSS reset on this page? If not, you should. It might help with inconsistencies like this. For example http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: You really should create a JSFiddle or a temporary page where we can see this in effect.

Comment: Here is an example in JSFiddle. I made the header all black and put in the background I'm using. Change the width of the browser window slowly and you will see the black header move back and forth ever so slightly.

http://jsfiddle.net/M4Lms/embedded/result/

Comment: It's just the browser re-rendering the page on change

Comment: But if you keep the width right at the wrong spot, the image stays "off" in the page, which looks bad when it's doing it to my top menu (see that first image that I linked to). How do I get it to not render every time? Or render to the correct position?